# How can I safely purge the archival contents of /var/log and how do I change log retention policies?

Tags: disk-usage, log, syslog

The contents of /var/log on my system are now taking up 80% of my hard drive and it's causing a lot of problems.

So I need to purge all the old contents but for some reason `sudo rm -rf "*.gz"` does not remove those old files.  Also weirdly enough I'm not 100% sure that all the logfiles I can see actually amount to the huge disk usage I'm dealing with.  Why would the Disk Usage Analysis tool show over 600GB used in /var/log when I can't find that much usage with ls?

Also, going forward I'd like to make sure this doesn't happen any more so I want to change the log file retention or rotation policies (however they're named).

EDIT:  The `du` command shows me that the syslog.1 takes up 597GB.  How do I change the way that whatever makes that log works to avoid this?

Edit2:  I think this link shows the root cause but I don't know what to do about it.  https://www.mail-archive.com/kernel-packages@lists.launchpad.net/msg386959.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by examining the log and find what is filling it up. Then fix that issue.

ALL log files in /var/log/ that end in .gz are old compressed log files and can be deleted with

```
sudo rm -rf *.gz
```

That will leave the current logs intact. Those SHOULD end in `.log`.  If a log ending on a digit gets lines added (where it should add them to `*.log`  you will need to examine the software that adds to this log. There will be a mistake in one of the configuration files.

Make sure the permissions to *.log are correct. That could also be an issue.

- `syslog` should be `-rw-r----- 1 root adm`
- `mysql.log` should be `-rw-r----- 1 mysql     adm`
- `apache2` is a directory and should be `drwxr-x--- 2 root      adm`
  The 2 files in there should be `-rw-r----- 1 root adm`

If you need to empty ACTIVE log files do not use `rm` but use `> /var/log/{logfile}`. That will keep the permissions of the file, empty it and keep the file on disk present.

Comment: Thanks for your help!  I have discovered that the same error was filling up the log whenever I had VLC running.  So I basically had 600GB of "vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer features failure:".   Other than not playing videos any more, I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: You could disable logging in vlc. That would stop it filling your log files. And it is a bug in vlc from the looks of it.

Comment: I am not sure that it's actually VLC itself that is doing the logging.  At least that is the impression I have from reading up on this.  VLC seems to have closed the bug on their end. https://trac.videolan.org/vlc/ticket/22734